# References not sorted properly by author-year

Tags: r-markdown, knitr, bibtex, bibliography, pandoc-citeproc

I'm working on a markdown `Rmd` document with references in several `.bib` BibTeX databases. The `yaml` header includes:

```
---
title: "title"
author: "me"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B, %Y')`"
output:
  bookdown::word_document2:
    reference_docx: StylesTemplate.docx
    number_sections: false
bibliography:
  - "`r system('kpsewhich graphics.bib', intern=TRUE)`"
  - "`r system('kpsewhich statistics.bib', intern=TRUE)`"
  - "`r system('kpsewhich timeref.bib', intern=TRUE)`"
  - "`r system('kpsewhich Rpackages.bib', intern=TRUE)`"
csl: apa.csl
---
```

I am stymied in how to get the following references to sort in the correct author-year order. The first two are out of order.

[image]

I am aware that `pandoc-citeproc` with a `.csl` file attempts to **disambiguate** authors when there are different spellings, but I checked my `.bib` files and all of these Tukey publications have one of:

```
author = {John W. Tukey}
author = {Tukey, John W.}
```

so they should be considered the same.

The first 4 references in my BibTeX files are:

```
@InProceedings{Tukey:1975:picturing,
  author    = {John W. Tukey},
  booktitle = {Proceedings of the International Congress of Mathematicians, Vancouver},
  title     = {Mathematics and the picturing of data},
  year      = {1975},
  pages     = {523--531},
  volume    = {2},
}

@Techreport{Tukey:1993:TR,
  author      = "John W. Tukey",
  title       = "Exploratory Data Analysis: Past, Present, and Future",
  institution = "Department of Statistics, Princeton University",
  year        = "1993",
  number      = "No. 302",
  month       = apr,
  url         = "https://apps.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a266775.pdf",
}

@Article{Tukey:59,
  author  = {John W. Tukey},
  journal = {Technometrics},
  title   = {A Quick, Compact, Two Sample Test to {Duckworth's} Specifications},
  year    = {1959},
  pages   = {31--48},
  volume  = {1},
  doi     = {10.2307/1266308},
  url     = {https://www.jstor.org/stable/1266308},
}

@article{Tukey:1962,
    Author = {John W. Tukey},
    Journal = {The Annals of Mathematical Statistics},
    Number = {1},
    Pages = {1--67},
    Publisher = {Institute of Mathematical Statistics},
    Title = {The Future of Data Analysis},
    Url = {http://www.jstor.org/stable/2237638},
    Volume = {33},
    Year = {1962},
    }
```

I see minor differences in formatting, but these should not affect `pandoc-citeproc` sorting.

Is this perhaps a bug in `pandoc-citeproc` or is there something I can do in my `.bib` files to avoid this?

I'm running R 4.1.3 under R Studio 2022.02.1, with pandoc 2.17.1.1

**Update**

I re-ran this using the `chicago-author-date.csl` style. All the references now sort correctly, so there must be something peculiar with the `apa.csl` style. I'd still prefer `apa.csl` style, so it would be of interest to understand why the difference.

[image]

Comment: The different spellings *should* be considered the same – but did you actually try to make the spellings identical? This could pin down the problem. Moreover, did you try compiling a regular (and minimal) TEX file with these references? This could rule out that the issue is related to knitr/pandoc/....

Comment: Yes, I used `grep -i "author.*Tukey"` on each of my `.bib` files and resolved all of these to be the same, "John W. Tukey", or "Tukey, John W." But the difference between the result of `apa.csl` and `chicago-author-date.csl` tells me that there is something there causing what I get.